# Mutate to obtain values before and after a value

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I have a a data set with a format similar to:

```
amount | event
------ | ------
 3     |  FALSE
 4     |  FALSE
 6     |  TRUE
 7     |  FALSE
 3     |  FALSE
 4     |  TRUE
 8     |  FALSE
```

And want to split and mutate based on the values of the `event` column, and create new columns that are populated with the values just before and after a row only if the value of `event` is TRUE. For example:

```
amount | event | before | after
------ | ----- | -----  | -----
 3     | FALSE |  NA    | NA
 4     | FALSE |  NA    | NA
 6     | TRUE  |  4     | 7
 7     | FALSE |  NA    | NA
 3     | FALSE |  NA    | NA
 4     | TRUE  |  3     | 8
 8     | FALSE |  NA    | NA
```

I'm thinking of `ddply` with `mutate`, but not sure how to access values according to an offset after the split. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(before=ifelse(event,lag(amount),NA),
         after =ifelse(event,lead(amount),NA))

#  amount event before after
#1      3 FALSE     NA    NA
#2      4 FALSE     NA    NA
#3      6  TRUE      4     7
#4      7 FALSE     NA    NA
#5      3 FALSE     NA    NA
#6      4  TRUE      3     8
#7      8 FALSE     NA    NA
```

where `d` is your sample data set:

```
d <- structure(list(amount = c(3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8), event = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("amount", "event"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: While the declarative nature of this answer is nicer, I can't quite get it working because: 1) `leads` isn't defined and 2) using `lag(amount, 1)` results in the same as `lag(amount)`.

Comment: 1) it should be `lead`, not `leads`. 2) I can't see a problem here.

Answer (score 5):

Using `base R`, we find the position of `TRUE` values in the 'event' column with `which` ('indx'), create two NA columns ('before' and 'after'), then we assign the 'amount' values that are at positions 1 below and 1 above the 'indx' to 'before' and 'after' columns

```
indx <- which(df1$event)
df1[c('before','after')] <- NA
df1$before[indx] <- df1$amount[indx-1]
df1$after[indx] <- df1$amount[indx+1]
 df1
 #  amount event before after
 #1      3 FALSE     NA    NA
 #2      4 FALSE     NA    NA
 #3      6  TRUE      4     7
 #4      7 FALSE     NA    NA
 #5      3 FALSE     NA    NA
 #6      4  TRUE      3     8
 #7      8 FALSE     NA    NA
```

Or using `data.table` (similar to @Marat Talipov's idea), we can use `shift` to get the `lag` and `lead` values of 'amount' to create the columns 'before/after'.  We change the rows in those columns corresponding to `FALSE` values in 'event' (`!event`) as NA.

```
 library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5
 setDT(df1)[,c('before', 'after'):= list(shift(amount, type='lag'),
    shift(amount, type='lead')) ][(!event), 3:4 := NA][]
 #     amount event before after
 #1:      3 FALSE     NA    NA
 #2:      4 FALSE     NA    NA
 #3:      6  TRUE      4     7
 #4:      7 FALSE     NA    NA
 #5:      3 FALSE     NA    NA
 #6:      4  TRUE      3     8
 #7:      8 FALSE     NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(amount = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L), 
event = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("amount", 
"event"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: +1 for starting with base R and then showing how to accomplish the same within library(data.table).  For those of us relatively new to R it is useful to first consider how something might be accomplished with base commands and then translate to data.table or dplyr, both of which make such accomplished use of base and the implications of base.  My case is slightly different and I may open a new question, but the working example above got me going. Thanks, Chris

Comment: @Chris I am updating with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

`df1 <- structure(list(smp = 1:17, x = c(609, 609, 609, 625, 625, 608, 
608, 608, 608, 608, 608, 608, 630, 631, 605, 603, 602), y = c(449, 
446, 446, 460, 455, 445, 445, 445, 445, 445, 445, 445, 459, 459, 
446, 448, 452), blink = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE)), .Names = c("smp", "x", "y", "blink"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))`

In this data instance where there are multiple TRUE values, a different approach may need to be taken to indexing to get values actually before and after a condition of interest as the above base approach will return values within the condition of interest.

Consider you want SpatialPoints before and after the condition and then want to compare the before distance to a given point and the after condition to a given point.  In that instance you want the point (just) before the condition and (just) after, and probably don't want the betweeners.  Akin to akrun's answer above, this suggests adjusting both the index on the Left Hand Side (LHS) and Right Hand Side (RHS). Adjusting the index of both the LHS and RHS provides the opportunity of a second logical test of 'outsideness' of the condition of interest (either before or after) that the above approach doesn't address in the case where there are multiple T's after an F and followed by an F, i.e. F, T, T, T, F, F.

`head(df1, n = 17)
   smp   x   y blink
1    1 609 449 FALSE
2    2 609 446 FALSE
3    3 609 446  TRUE
4    4 625 460 FALSE
5    5 625 455 FALSE
6    6 608 445  TRUE
7    7 608 445  TRUE
8    8 608 445 FALSE
9    9 608 445 FALSE
10  10 608 445  TRUE
11  11 608 445  TRUE
12  12 608 445  TRUE
13  13 630 459 FALSE
14  14 631 459 FALSE
15  15 605 446  TRUE
16  16 603 448  TRUE
17  17 602 452 FALSE`

`df1[c('pre_x', 'pre_y', 'post_x', 'post_y')] <- NA`

In this instance the pre_x/pre_y, post_x/post_y will eventually be cbind coords and thence SpatialPoints; but, this comes after establishing what is before and after. Your use case may differ, but the logic should hold.

`indx_1 <- which(df1$blink)`

`indx_1
[1]  3  6  7 10 11 12 15 16`

Then using indx_1 to calculate pre_x, pre_y, post_x, post_y:

`df1$pre_x[indx_1 - 1] <- df1$x[indx_1 - 1]
df1$pre_y[indx_1 - 1] <- df1$y[indx_1 - 1]
df1$post_x[indx_1 + 1] <- df1$post_x[indx_1 + 1]
df1$post_y[indx_1 + 1] <- df1$post_y[indx_1 + 1]`

`> head(df1, n = 17)
   smp   x   y blink pre_x pre_y post_x post_y
1    1 609 449 FALSE    NA    NA     NA     NA
2    2 609 446 FALSE   609   446     NA     NA
3    3 609 446  TRUE    NA    NA     NA     NA
4    4 625 460 FALSE    NA    NA    625    460
5    5 625 455 FALSE   625   455     NA     NA
6    6 608 445  TRUE   608   445     NA     NA
7    7 608 445  TRUE    NA    NA    608    445
8    8 608 445 FALSE    NA    NA    608    445
9    9 608 445 FALSE   608   445     NA     NA
10  10 608 445  TRUE   608   445     NA     NA
11  11 608 445  TRUE   608   445    608    445
12  12 608 445  TRUE    NA    NA    608    445
13  13 630 459 FALSE    NA    NA    630    459
14  14 631 459 FALSE   631   459     NA     NA
15  15 605 446  TRUE   605   446     NA     NA
16  16 603 448  TRUE    NA    NA    603    448
17  17 602 452 FALSE    NA    NA    602    452`

Now the desired values are written outside the condition of interest
and reliably report the before and after values.  In addition,
a before index (indx_2) and after (indx_3) can be used to select for further processing, in my case making coordinates for SpatialPoints.

`indx_2 <- which(!df1$blink & !is.na(df1$pre_x))`

`indx_3 <- which(!df1$blink & !is.na(df1$post_x))`

`coords_pre <- cbind(x = df1$pre_x[indx_2], y = df1$pre_y[indx_2])`

`coords_post <- cbind( x = df1$post_x[indx_3], y = df1$post_y[indx_3])`

`library(sp)`
`pre_blink_sp <- SpatialPoints(coords_pre)`
`> summary(pre_blink_sp)
Object of class SpatialPoints
Coordinates:
  min max
x 608 631
y 445 459
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]
Number of points: 4`

Having sorted out how to do this in base, albeit ploddingly, df1$smp
is there to setkey() as I now try to figure out how to accomplish the same in data.table.